# || with an argument greater than 1

Tags: r

The `if()` function below broke due to the R 4.2.0 update that throws a warning when `&&` or `||` are used with an argument of length greater than 1. It's being called when I run [this function](https://github.com/strengejacke/esc/blob/master/R/esc_mean_gain.R) from the `esc` package, and I'm not sure of how to move forward.

What would be the most robust/future-proof way to fix it?

```
  if ((missing(gain1mean) || is.null(gain1mean) || is.na(gain1mean)) &&
      ((missing(pre1mean) || is.null(pre1mean) || is.na(pre1mean)) ||
       (missing(post1mean) || is.null(post1mean) || is.na(post1mean)))) {
    warning("Either `pre1mean` and `post1mean` or `gain1mean` must be specified.", call. = F)
    return(esc_generic(es = NA, v = NA, es.type = es.type, grp1n = NA, grp2n = NA, info = NA, study = NA))
  }
```

Comment: Simple. To ensure not to use a vector of more than one element in if statement. Why would you want to pass a vector with 2 or more elements to if?

Comment: @Onyambu see above; it's in an existing function I'm trying to use

Comment: Yes, ensure that what you pass to if else statement is of length 1. Otherwise it should break

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it looks like the below fixes it.

```
any(missing(gain1mean), is.null(gain1mean), is.na(gain1mean)) &&
  any(missing(pre1mean), is.null(pre1mean), is.na(pre1mean)) ||
  any(missing(post1mean), is.null(post1mean), is.na(post1mean))
```